# Am I harming myself by having two domains pointing at the same thing?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO and multiple domains to same site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/seo-and-multiple-domains-to-same-site)

I have a domain I recently purchased. I went ahead and pointed it at my website(via DNS) and by default, my server now serves my website on this new domain. Eventually, the new domain will replace my old domain(with 302 redirects and all that). However, I've not yet got my website ready for that because I'll need to do some rebranding and such.

Am I actively hurting my SEO ratings and such by having these two domains point to the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  Google will penalise a site for duplicate content.  It depends on who Google thinks is the authoritative site for the content.  My advice is to quickly put redirect rules in the old site to redirect content (301 permanent redirects) so that GoogleBot easily understands that the content has migrated.

Comment: I instead just removed the DNS entries for the domain so it no longer resolves. I've yet to even put up a hyperlink containing the domain, yet I saw it on 6th page of google already for a search term I'm 1st page on

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes. I have seen cases where people had a 1st page rank built up with SEO and had 2 domains (same name, but different TLD) without 301 from one to the other and were penalized so badly by Google made them lose their 1st page rank. And Google can do this at any day any time, so you'd better set up 301's yesterday if you have good ranks built up with SEO.